# Different Ruby behavior inside the view versus IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what happens when I run the following code through the Interactive Ruby Interpreter:

```
start_date = '2015-03-22'
month_and_year = Date.parse(start_date).strftime("%B %Y")
puts month_and_year
```

Output:

```
March 2015
```

I have the same code in one of my views:

```
         <% require 'date' %>
         ...........
         <% logger.info(@event.start_date ) %>
         <% start_date = @event.start_date %>
Line 64: <% logger.info(__LINE__) %>
         <% month_and_year = Date.parse(start_date).strftime("%B %Y") %>
         <% logger.info(__LINE__) %>
```

Here's the log file output:

```
2015-03-22
64
  Rendered events/_event_sidebar.html.erb (87.3ms)
  Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (545.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1099ms
```

Why is the same code fragment causing a 500 error in the view?

Comment: In rails views you can avoid using `strftime` and use the `I18n` helpers to render the proper formats, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats for more info, i.e. `I18n.localize(@event.start_date, format: :month_year)` where you define `month_year` in `config/locales/*.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@event.start_date` is  not a string and [`Date.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) expects the first parameter to be `string`.

In your `irb`, you are supplying string `2015-03-22` to `Date.parse`, and it succeeded.  But in your `erb`, it's not a `string` but possibly a `Date` type.

So, use `strftime` on `@event.start_date` in `erb` as:

```
<% month_and_year = @event.start_date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was the incompatible type. Your suggestion worked.